# AngularJS - how to trigger filter on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-filter, angularjs-ng-click

I'm trying to make simple multi-language website.
I have a small controller just to be able to change current language in root scope:

```
   app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
       $rootScope.currentLang = 'en_US';
       $scope.switchLang = function(){
            if($rootScope.currentLang ==='en_US'){
                $rootScope.currentLang = 'cs_CS';
            } else {
                $rootScope.currentLang = 'en_US';
            }
        }
    });
```

And I want to store my data in filter:

```
   app.filter('ci18n', function($rootScope){
       return function(id_text){
           var translations = {
               'en_US' : {
                   'GREETING' : 'Hi'
               },
               'cs_CS' : {
                   'GREETING' : 'Cau'  
               }
            };

            return translations[$rootScope.currentLang][id_text];
        };
    });
```

Problem is that my website does't change with rootScope change.
I need an idea how to solve it better or how to trigger filter again to change my texts.

Here is how I use the filter

```
<p>greet: {{'GREETING' | ci18n}}</p>
```

Comment: Did you try with `$scope.$apply();`?

Comment: I tried that inside of switchLang() function with no change.

Comment: Is cs_CS a C# locale?  Or did you mean cs_CZ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Starting from Angular 1.3, [filters are assumed to be stateless](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/11/19/exploring-angular-1.3-stateful-filters.html) in order to speed things up in the common case. That means Anguar won't re-evaluate your filter if its input has not changed. Angular has no idea that you're also reading `$rootScope.currentLang` within the filter implementation, so it doesn't know that the filter needs to be re-evaluated if `currentLang` changes.

The solution is to mark your filter as stateful explicitly:

```
    app.filter('ci18n', function($rootScope){
       var filter = function(id_text){
           var translations = {
               'en_US' : {
                   'GREETING' : 'Hi'
               },
               'cs_CS' : {
                   'GREETING' : 'Cau'  
               }
            };

            return translations[$rootScope.currentLang][id_text];
        };

        filter.$stateful = true; // <-- the magic line

        return filter;
    });
```

Of course this does come with a performance penalty, but since your filter is just a map lookup, that shouldn't have much of an impact.

Comment: Thanks a lot for perfectly clear answer, worked great.

Comment: @JanOmacka just a suggestion. Do accept the answer if it solves/addresses your issue(s)!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to hit the button, thanks for the remind.

Comment: Upgraded angular from 1.2 to 1.4 and lost the ability to change locale dynamically for some of my custom filters, $stateful really is the magic line here! Thanks